# How to make 2 TextViews Scrollable without making the layout Scrollable?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am having an issue but I did not get any answers in my search.

I am using 1 `EditText` and 2 `TextView`s one below the other and if the `TextView`'s capacity increases it doesn't add to it and I am not able to make it scrollable.

I need to add the infinite text for them.

I need both the text view as scrollable.

please help me out finding the solution.

I have tried:

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"  
android:scrollbars = "vertical"

yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

and 

    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linear1">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TEXT_STATUS_ID"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>

 mTextStatus = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.TEXT_STATUS_ID );
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById( R.id.SCROLLER_ID );

 private void scrollToBottom()
 {
  mScrollView.post(new Runnable()
   {
     public void run()
      {
        mScrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mTextStatus.getBottom());
      }
     });
     }
```

And I want to show the `TextView` text only 3 lines and later by not knowing the length of the text if any more text means it should be scrollable.

Please help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

when I make na **App** and whant only textview to **scrolls** i added this:

```
testeview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

After set textview text you can try that.

So my **xml** is that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent">





    <TextView

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"

        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:text="New Text"

        android:id="@+id/textView"

        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and my **java** class:

```
TextView textview;
associacao=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        //texto do separador Share

        associacao.setText("A Share – Associação para a Partilha do Conhecimento, é uma associação sem fins lucrativos constituída por profissionais seniores com carreiras de sucesso e com capacidade de iniciativa, disponibilidade de tempo e interesse em partilhar o seu saber, trabalhando essencialmente para os jovens, numa base de voluntariado.\n" +

                "\n" +

                "Como principais pilares de actuação, a Sharededica-se ao tema da empregabilidade e ao apoio ao empreendedorismo.\n" +

                "\n" +

                "Ao longo dos anos de actividade da Share, a situação do país e principalmente as dificuldades\n" +

                "\n" +

                "acrescidas dos jovens na entrada no mercado de trabalho e a existência de muitos reformados com valor e conhecimentos críticos vieram dar mais força à nossa missão.\n" +

                "Criada em 2006, a Share formenta o diálogo inter-geracional identificando nos seniores:\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Conhecimento;\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Network;\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Disponibilidade;\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Motivação.\n" +

                "\n" +

                "E nos jovens:\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Capacidade de aprender;\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Hard/Soft skills;\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Empreendedorismo;\n" +

                "\n" +

                "– Dinamismo.\n" +

                "\n" +

                "Acreditamos que é neste diálogo de partilha que vamos contribuir para uma sociedade melhor.\n" +

                "\n" +

                "A Share conta actualmente com mais de uma centena de associados efectivos e tem sede no Porto e um núcleo de associados em Lisboa.\n\n\n");

        // inicia funcao de scroll

        scroll();
```

and the **scroll** method:

```
private void scroll(){

        //conteudo da funcao de scroll

        associacao.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure about your answer i need to show my text only lines if any text added also it should show 3 lines when more text added means it should be scrollable..! @BrunoFerreira

Comment: If you dont add text it dont do nothing because the textview dont have more text than the screen size, if you have more text than screen size the textview becomes scrollable. You cam try my code if do what you whant fine, if not just send a reply to know! @AjayJain

Comment: if i understand you only want to show 3 line and makes scrollable if the text is more than screen size

Comment: I don't want to be scrollable if the text is more than the 3 lines.. I told it must be displayed only 3 lines whatever the text size may be.. it must be scrollable to that 3 lines only !